# Custom Lookup For Multiple Field in PageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce, lookup

I want populate custom lookup in table for multpile fields
[image]

For single Teacher lookup it is working fine 
I am reffering to [Jeff Douglas Custom lookup](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/)

How to implement the same in Page block table?

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable style="width:100%" value="{!firstSession}" var="fs" title="PageBlock Tab">
<apex:column style="width:150px" headerValue="Day">
            <apex:outputText value="{!fs.Session_Day__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column style="width:230px" headerValue="Start Date/Time">
                  <apex:outputText value="{0,date,d/M/yyyy hh:mm a}">
                  <apex:param value="{!fs.Start_Date_Time__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column style="width:230px" headerValue="End Date/Time">
            <apex:outputText value="{0,date,d/M/yyyy hh:mm a}">
                <apex:param value="{!fs.End_Date_Time__c}"/>
            </apex:outputText>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Teacher">
            <apex:outputPanel styleclass="requiredInput">
                  <apex:outputPanel styleclass="requiredBlock"/>
                 <apex:inputfield value="{!fs.Teacher__c}" id="teacher">
                </apex:inputfield>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Room">
        <apex:outputPanel styleclass="requiredInput">
                  <apex:outputPanel styleclass="requiredBlock"/>
            <apex:inputfield value="{!fs.Room__c}">
            </apex:inputfield>
             </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Is there anybuddy to help me here?